# Whether JVM runs in User Process or Separate Process

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot, java-threads

I have read JVM as a Process and as a deamon thread and 
As per Java, Each process has its own JVM and Garbage collector

Could some one please explain me with more details on this.

"Whether JVM runs on User Application Process or in Separate process." ??

Everywhere, I read it as an instance for Application Process.
And I also read it as GC has multiple threads.

Whether GC is a separate process or it creates threads on User process.?

Comment: GC is never a separate process. It is uses just one or more threads in each JVM process.

Comment: Java supports Threads.  It is up to each implementation to decide how to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/150978/robert, Is JVM a separate process for each Application Process ?

Comment: @candy To answer to someone, use their name preceded by an at-sign like `@candy` rather than a link to their profile.

Comment: The JVM is always a single process started by `java ...`. There are containers allowing to run multiple applications in a single JVM, like e.g. Servlets, where each Servlet is mostly isolated from the others (they still share memory, CPU, and some global data). +++ The GC is very tightly coupled to many other parts of the JVM, so it can't be a separate process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. JVM is running inside a process that was started by executing `java.exe`/`javaw.exe` on Windows or the `java` executable for Unix/GNU. Its owner would be the one that runs the executable. If two java programs are running then two JVMs in different processes will be created.
2. GC is a thread inside the JVM, see [here](http://www.javaperspective.com/daemon-threads.html)

> For example, the Java garbage collector is a daemon thread.

Comment: Hi Dabiuteef , Thanks for info and link. My Straight question Is JVM a Separate Process away from user Process ?

Comment: @candy It runs in whatever context you started it up in. Run a long-lived Java app and look at the process owner.

Comment: @Dabiuteef, Thankyou so much for the Answer. My question is answered and I accepted ur Answer

Answer (score 0):

A JVM can be started from within an existing process via `JNI_CreateJavaVM`. A JVM generally consists of multiple threads, whether it runs within an owning process or as a separate process. The term "application" is on a different abstraction level than processes and threads.

Comment: Agreed application term is mentioned for easy catch sake. I believe Multiple threads in JVM are for the sake of GCs. Is there any other threads in JVM